# Polynomials approximate $L^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation

Suppose $(\Omega, \mu)$ is measurable space with $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, here $\Omega$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. $f,g\in L^2(\Omega)$ with $\mu(\{x:f(x)=0\})=0$. I want to find polynomial $p$ s.t. $pf$ can approximate $g$ in $L^2$ norm. Concretely, for any $\varepsilon>0$, how to construct polynomial $p_{\varepsilon}$ s.t.
$$
\|p_{\varepsilon}f-g\|_{L^2(\Omega)}<\varepsilon.
$$
I tried to decompose space $\Omega$ as $\Omega=\cup_{n\geq1}E_n$, where
$$
E_n=\{x:\frac1n<|f(x)|<n\}.
$$
so $g/f\in L^2(E_n)$. Take polynomial $p_k$ s.t. $\|p_k-g/f\|_{L^2(E_n)}^2<\eta_{n, k}$, which is a small number ready to defined. And we have
$$
\int_{\Omega}|p_kf-g|^2=\int_{E_n}|p_k-g/f|^2|f|^2+\int_{\Omega\setminus E_n}|p_kf-g|^2\\
\leq n^2\eta_{n,k}+\int_{\Omega\setminus E_n}|p_kf-g|^2.
$$
Since $p_kf-g\in L^2(\Omega)$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $\delta_{k}$ s.t. for any measurable set $E$ and $\mu(E)<\delta_{k}$ we have
$$
\int_E|p_kf-g|^2<\varepsilon.
$$
If $\mu(\Omega\setminus E_n)<\delta_k$, we have
$$
\int_{\Omega\setminus E_n}|p_kf-g|^2<\varepsilon.
$$
this need that for $k$ fixed, $n$ must be large enough. but in order that $n^2\eta_{n,k}$ small enough, $k$ must be large enough for any fixed $n$.

I have no idea how to deal with it. But the original problem is

> If $\mu$ is compactly supported measure on $\mathbb{C}$ and $f\in L^2(\mu)$, then $f$ is star-cyclic vector for $N_{\mu}$ if and only if $\mu(\{x:f(x)=0\})=0$.

Here $N_{\mu}$ is a normal operator defined on $L^2(\mu)$ as $(N_{\mu}f)z=zf(z)$ and $f$ is star-cyclic vector for $N_{\mu}$ means that
$$
L^2(\mu)=\overline{\{p(N_{\mu},N_{\mu}^*)f:p(x,y)\text{ is polynomial on $\mathbb{C}$}\}}.
$$
This problem is from A course in functional analysis written by Conway and it is Exercise 1 in Section 3 of Chapter 9.

Comment: Do you mean $\mu\{f=0\}=0$? Because otherwise if $f=0$ a.e. then what you claim cannot be possible. $||pf||_{L^{2}}=0$ and if $||g||_{L^{2}}>0$ then you cannot possibly hope to approximate a non-zero vector by a zero vector in the normed space $L^{2}(\mu)$

Comment: You are right. That's a typo. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score -1):

We just need to show that
$$
\overline{\{p(z)f(z)\ |\ p\text{ is polynomial}\}}=L^2(\Omega).
$$
Since $L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space, so we can consider $g\in\overline{\{p(z)f(z)\ |\ p\text{ is polynomial}\}}^{\perp}$, that means
$$
\int_{\Omega}p(z)f(z)\overline{g(z)}\mathrm{d}\mu=0.\quad\forall p\text{ polynomial}.
$$
Since the subspace consisting of polynomials is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$, we get $f\bar{g}=0$, $\mu$-a.e. But $f\neq0$ $\mu$-a.e., impose $g=0$ $\mu$-a.e.

Comment: Firstly, a polynomial as a function from a arbitrary set to the real line does not make much sense. Rather, I think that you want $\Omega$ to be a compact subset of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Next, $f\overline{g}\in L^{1}(\Omega)$. In that case, if you are thinking of approximating $f\overline{g}$ by $p$, then what you get is $\int_{\Omega}|f\overline{g}|^{2}=0$ but you don't yet know that $f\overline{g}\in L^{2}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Or if you were thinking of using Legendre polynomials then too you will run into trouble. So I don't know how you justified the jump that $<fg,p>=0$ for all $p$ implies $fg=0$

Comment: Instead, if $f$ or $g$ is $L^{2+\delta}$ for some $\delta>0$, let's say $f$. Then you can approximate $sgn(f\overline{g})$ by $p$ in $L^{\frac{2(2+\delta)}{\delta}}$ and then use Holder's inequality to conclude that $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}|f\overline{g}|\,d\mu=0$ which gives you your required conclusion.

Comment: Sorry for your confuse. Here we take $\Omega$ as a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ under usual topology and measure. We can define a new measure $\nu$ as $\mathrm{d}\nu=|fg|\mathrm{d}\mu$, and we can get $\nu=0$ since $\int p\mathrm{d}\nu=0$ for all polynomial $p$. This forces $fg=0$.

Comment: Uh...no. $\int p\,d\nu$ is not $0$. If you define $\nu$ as the signed (complex) measure $d\nu =fg\,d\mu$ then you have that $\int p\,d\nu=0$.  That does not tell you anything about whether $\int p|fg|\,d\mu=\langle p,|fg|\rangle$ is $0$ or not. Secondly, as I said, to conclude the jump from polynomials to $\int_{\Omega}|fg|$ vanishing or $\int_{\Omega}|fg|^{2}$ vanishing, I think you'll end up needing more assuptions. Like I said, if you assume $f\in L^{2+\delta}$ then it's fine. Otherwise if $fg\in L^{2}$ , then too it is fine.

Comment: In any case, if $\int p |fg|\,d\mu=0$ , then it is trivial that $fg=0$ as you can just take $p=1$.

Comment: You mean if $\nu$ is complex measure and $\int p\mathrm{d}\nu=0$ for all polynomials $p$, we cannot get $\mathrm{d}\nu$ directly? If you are right, I have no idea how to deal with this problem. But I find a similar problem from A course in functional analysis written by Conway (GTM 96). In Section 3 (Star-cyclic normal operators) of Chapter 9 (Normal operators on Hilbert space), it set the problem as Exercise 1. Are there some techniques from star-cyclic normal operators can be used to solve this?

Comment: Well I mainly study probability so I'll give an example from Probability theory. There are something called Log normal distributions. There are infinitely many distinct distributions on the real line with the same moments (See Durrett' book Moment problem section). So infact, there are two distinct probabikity measures on the real line $\mu$ and $nu$ such that $\int x^n d\mu=\int x^n d\nu$ for all n but $\mu\neq \nu$. In this case, things might be more complicated as the measures are compactly supported. But its certainly not as trivial as you are making it out to be. I'll have to think on it.

Comment: It's also wise to state the source of your original problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have modified the question.